# How do I extract the files from 2 harddisk that merge in 1 partition?

Tags: hard-disk

I have a computer using 2 hdd and merge into 1 partition.
The windows is corrupted and cannot turn on.

How do I extract the files from these harddisk?

Comment: How is your corrupt Windows related to Unix?

Comment: So basically you want to create a backup of your 2 HDDs? And what do you mean "2 harddisk that merge in 1 partition" in your title - are you referring to a RAID configuration, or do you simply want to copy the content of 2 HDDs to one partition in the target? Please edit your post to clarify ...

Answer (score 0):

First, you should identify the technology used to merge the 2 HDDs into a single partition.

Is it perhaps Windows Dynamic Disk? For that, you'll need the `ldmtool create all` command to make Linux recognize the layout and create a device that allows accessing the 2 disks as a single device; the name of the package containing the command is probably `libldm` or `ldmtool` depending on your Linux distribution.

If it's some sort of BIOS RAID, `dmraid` might be able to make it accessible on Linux. The `dmraid -r` command should try and list all RAID sets `dmraid` can identify and describe the format used and other essential information. `dmraid -ay` will attempt to activate any discovered software RAID sets that are understood by `dmraid`.

The tool that will allow you to access the Dynamic Disk/RAID in each case will usually present a `/dev/mapper/<something>` device that can be mounted like a regular disk or partition device. If it's from a Windows system, you can be pretty sure the filesystem type is going to be NTFS.

---

If it's some sort of hardware RAID, you'll need to know the exact type and model of the hardware RAID controller; some of them use proprietary metadata formats that are not understood by Linux without the RAID controller, so you'll either need the controller working, or have to reverse-engineer the data layout and hand-craft a device-mapper configuration that will replicate what the RAID controller would do.

**Note:** If the disks are from a hardware RAID controller that has failed, and you wish to transfer them to another controller of same type, be very careful. Find the documentation for that RAID controller model and find out the exact steps you'll need to do to import an existing RAID configuration to the controller: some controllers will treat previously-unseen disks as empty unless specifically told otherwise, and will often offer a very easy way to create a new empty RAID set out of them. Obviously, **you must not do that in this case** as it would do further damage to your data.